# Autostretch datagrid within a window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I've created a datagrid and placed it in a spot in a WPF form.

Now what I'm trying to do is have the datagrid change its size keeping the same proportions as its original placement with the WPF window changing size (hopefully that makes sense).

I've tried setting autostretch to true but that hasn't helped.

Comment: Have you tried setting your left and right margin values so that the grid is forced to stretch/shrink in relation to the form?

Answer (score 2):

Got my computer with Visual Studio in my office, so can't test it :) but shouldn't this work if you set the alignments to stretch?

datagridObj.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
datagridObj.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

Answer (score 2):

Sure it makes sense, but it sounds like you don't really understand how the WPF layout system works, and unless you do it will be really painful going forward. The short story is, you need to have an appropriate container - I recommend Grid - and have your DataGrid placed in that container. Then you can set margins and so on for the DataGrid to place it however you like, and provided it has its Width and Height set to Auto, it will keep with its parent container.

Now if you have several other controls in the picture, of course it's a bit more involved, but I still recommend keeping with Grids and splitting them into however many rows and columns you require, then setting the appropriate values for their Height/Width respectively - you can make some columns fixed in width, or a multiple of other column, or leave them as Auto and they will take up the remainder of the space.

The topic is much more involved of course, but you can find a quick primer on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx

If you'll remember just one thing, it should be this: Grids represent fluid layouts in WPF, use them as much as possible as opposed to Canvases. Of course StackPanel and DockPanel etc. have their own specific uses.

P.S. The visual studio designer makes a bit of mess of things usually, by setting margins and so on to make the drag and drop more intuitive, you should pay close attention to the properties it modifies and see if you're not better off positioning things manually by modifying the XAML (you usually are) once you sketched the layout out.

Answer (score 0):

just as example

```
<Window x:Class=""
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Margin="162,57,141,54"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

by default a `DataGrid` is

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
```

so you only need a Margin like **Arno Saxena** told you